# Deploy ClickOnce Application on SharePoint

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce application that I would like to deploy to a SharePoint location. I have included the path to the SharePoint location on my local machine as the Publishing Folder Location ("C:\Users%username%..."). However, I am unclear as to Installation Folder URL that I can use for this deployment? Is this the web URL for the same folder on the online version of SharePoint (\xxxxxx.sharepoint.com...)?

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete process for publishing to a shared folder.

Publish using ClickOnce and deploy using SharePoint.

Add a Document Library.

Create a new folder.

Select (Actions > Open with Explorer).

Copy the URL into the following folders:

Publishing Folder Location - \website.com\sites\name\folder

Installation Folder URL - website.com/sites/name/folder/

Click Prerequisities and untick "Create setup program in install prerequisite components"

Select (Build > Publish)

This should create a file at the top level (extension .vsto)
and a subfolder called "Application Files"